# How to build an Operating System for Motorola L7 phone?

Tags: operating-system, motorola

Is there a way for me to build my own Operating System for Motorola L7 phone?
How do I go about building it?
Are there any Online resources that can help?

Comment: Have you ever done any other type of OS-level development?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean make changes to the current software - you can't since it is closed source.

If you really mean to build your own operating system (or even reuse an existing one such as Linux and port it to the phone) - then you'll probably find that you can't find drivers (or even the components specifications in order to create your own drivers) - so at best you will end up with a crippled phone.

This is assuming you are even able to flash your software to the device (which you probably can't, either because the boot-loader would require a Motorola signature to load it, or because you can't get the necessary tools).